# instalação pacote Rstem no R

Tags: r

Olá, boa tarde!

Estou tentando fazer a instalação do pacote Rstem no R, por meio de um arquivo tar.gz, visto que o pacote foi descontinuado do CRAN. Estou usando a seguinte rotina, porém a instalação da erro, o que posso fazer para solucionar esse erro?

> install.packages("C:\projeto\Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ingle/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning: invalid package 'C:/projeto/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz'
>   Erro: ERROR: no packages specified
>   In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/projeto/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Olá @Ingled, para poder reproduzir a sua pergunta, forneça o local que você baixou o arquivo `tar.gz`, pois no erro diz que o pacote está inválido. Ainda, forneça o código que você utilizou para instalar o pacote.

Comment: Isto é Windows: `"C:\projeto\Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz"`. Tente com `/`: `"C:/projeto/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz"`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode instalar diretamente através do site http://www.omegahat.net/ a partir do seguinte comando:

```
install.packages("Rstem", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```